# How can i uncheck multiple select box options by class with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple multi-select boxes with the same class and i want to unselect all on an event. They have all a div with the same class `class_for_all_multi_selects` around them.

```
$("#element_to_uncheck_all_options").change(function() {
  $('.class_for_all_multi_selects'). ...?
});

<div class="class_for_all_multi_selects">
  <select multiple="multiple" name="1">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="class_for_all_multi_selects">
  <select multiple="multiple" name="2">
    <option value="1">option1</option>
    <option value="2">option2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How can i uncheck multiple select box options by class with jquery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also try this using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
 $("div.class_for_all_multi_selects option:selected").prop('selected',false);
```

check it out :  http://jsfiddle.net/EVrrz/3/

Comment: whoo, a lot of right answers, choosed this because of the jsfiddle demo.

Answer (score 3):

Use `removeAttr()` to remove the selected attribute from all options

```
$('select option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
```

Since you said `#element_to_uncheck_all_options` is a div, you should bind to `click` events instead of `change`

```
$("#element_to_uncheck_all_options").click(function() {
   $('select option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$("#element_to_uncheck_all_options").click(function() {
    $("div.class_for_all_multi_selects option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

And since you only want to *uncheck* all items, use `click` (with a button, or whatever) instead of `change`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.

```
$("#element_to_uncheck_all_options").click(function() {
    $(".class_for_all_multi_selects option").attr("selected", false);
});​
```

Now tested and works :)

Comment: Oh, those aren't checkboxes.  Hmm, wonder if it still works... not so much.  Revising...

Comment: I have no idea why I had such a hard time reading the question.  It's not that complicated.  Code now reflects question and actually works - see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXK8n/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd probably do it:

```
$('#selectAll').change(function() {
    $('.class_for_all_multi_selects option').prop('selected', this.checked);
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mSfdc/1) to demonstrate. This implements a select all / unselect all, but you could make it just de-select only by setting the this.checked to false instead.

Comment: @Starx: He used a checkbox for a selcect all/deselect all procedure. If you read the code, you will see that.

Comment: @Starx the divs he refers to are just containers for the selects. I used a checkbox to implement the #element_to_uncheck_all_options the OP refers to (but doesn't specify what input is actually used) - my example is for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Can just change value of the select to an empty value and jQuery will handle the rest, no loop required

```
 $('.class_for_all_multi_selects select').val('');
```